# Can we add a start offset value to glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

This is the draw call for glDrawElements

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicesTaperRectangle.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

can i add the start offset value like it should start from the 3rd index value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a named buffer object is bound to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, the last argument of [`glDrawElements`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) is treated as a byte offset as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store:

```cpp
auto offset = sizeof(unsigned int) * 3;
glDrawElements(
    GL_TRIANGLES,
    indicesTaperRectangle.size() - 3, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    (const void*)offset);
```